# Probability of 2 phones returning exactly same GPS co-ordinates, using Network_Provider on Android

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

What is the probability of 2 different android devices returning exactly the same GPS co-ordinates. According to the [wiki](http://wiki.xkcd.com/geohashing/GPS_accuracy), the 5th decimal place gives a accuracy of 1.1m, and the `onLocationChanged` returns upto 7 decimal points, meaning accuracy of 1cm. Now we also have to account for the fact that `GPS` technology itself will introduce some errors. From what I understand (and from my tests), phone kept at the same location is returning between 0.18143341 meters to 22 meters.

I need to know this to arrive at a realistic algorithm to identify people by their location. The question is, do I need to associate the identity of the person too in the mix of my equation or can I safely assume that 2 phones in the exactly same location will not return the exact same `GPS` (ever).

Thoughts anyone ?

Samples below (30 second apart)

```
02-21 14:18:48.679: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:19:18.678: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:19:48.668: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.11805124
02-21 14:20:18.797: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 6.563945
02-21 14:20:48.676: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.18143341
02-21 14:21:18.725: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:21:48.685: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 2.6022007
02-21 14:22:18.704: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 6.5060697
02-21 14:22:48.703: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 6.572767
02-21 14:23:18.662: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:23:48.772: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 6.563945
02-21 14:24:18.681: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.1327054
02-21 14:24:48.720: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 7.176328
02-21 14:25:18.700: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 7.6471653
02-21 14:25:48.609: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:26:18.708: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 7.790146
02-21 14:26:48.717: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 14.501556
02-21 14:27:18.797: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.1327054
02-21 14:27:48.676: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:28:18.705: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.19548245
02-21 14:28:48.704: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 23.221346
02-21 14:29:18.684: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.18143341
02-21 14:29:48.723: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 7.176328
02-21 14:30:18.662: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:30:48.752: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 6.3350186
02-21 14:31:18.691: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.18143341
02-21 14:31:48.670: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.18143341
02-21 14:32:18.679: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.1327054
02-21 14:32:48.699: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 7.411349
02-21 14:33:18.708: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.18143341
02-21 14:33:48.697: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 22.613928
02-21 14:34:18.666: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:34:48.686: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.11805124
02-21 14:35:18.675: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.18143341
02-21 14:35:48.664: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:36:18.663: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.19548245
02-21 14:36:48.693: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 22.190514
02-21 14:37:18.782: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 7.2989116
02-21 14:37:48.701: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 20.302017
02-21 14:38:18.721: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 22.503975
02-21 14:38:48.670: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:39:18.699: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.11805124
02-21 14:39:48.648: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.0
02-21 14:40:18.668: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:40:48.787: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.1327054
02-21 14:41:18.876: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.11805124
02-21 14:41:48.705: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.18583706
02-21 14:42:18.705: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 7.411349
02-21 14:42:48.664: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.0
02-21 14:43:18.703: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.11805124
02-21 14:43:48.692: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 15.474865
02-21 14:44:18.772: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.18143341
02-21 14:44:48.671: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:45:18.700: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:45:48.700: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 7.176328
02-21 14:46:18.699: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 22.503975
02-21 14:46:48.738: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 7.176328
02-21 14:47:18.677: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:47:48.677: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:48:18.676: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:48:48.885: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.19548245
02-21 14:49:18.674: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.18143341
02-21 14:49:48.694: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 6.524145
02-21 14:50:18.763: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.1327054
02-21 14:50:48.702: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 6.4802594
02-21 14:51:18.712: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 6.4802594
02-21 14:51:48.671: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.19548245
02-21 14:52:18.690: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 7.790146
02-21 14:52:48.689: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 4.656421
02-21 14:53:18.689: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 6.563945
02-21 14:53:48.768: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:54:18.667: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.11805124
02-21 14:54:48.726: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 6.524145
02-21 14:55:18.696: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 6.7189484
02-21 14:55:48.685: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.11805124
02-21 14:56:18.854: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.18143341
02-21 14:56:48.713: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 6.4802594
02-21 14:57:18.813: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 6.6248784
02-21 14:57:48.692: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 7.176328
02-21 14:58:18.731: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 6.524145
02-21 14:58:48.691: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.13724314
02-21 14:59:18.670: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.18143341
02-21 14:59:48.749: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 7.176328
02-21 15:00:18.688: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.18143341
02-21 15:00:48.748: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.22683989
02-21 15:01:18.797: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.22683989
02-21 15:01:48.716: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 21.353783
02-21 15:02:18.745: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.1327054
02-21 15:02:48.695: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.11805124
02-21 15:03:18.684: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.1327054
02-21 15:03:48.723: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 6.0702796
02-21 15:04:18.783: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.18143341
02-21 15:04:48.682: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.11805124
02-21 15:05:18.671: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.11805124
02-21 15:05:48.780: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.1327054
02-21 15:06:18.710: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 4.9840126
02-21 15:06:48.689: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.201804
02-21 15:07:18.728: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.18143341
02-21 15:07:48.687: D/Taxeeta:RegularUpdates(5511): Is location changed 0.11805124
```

Comment: `I'm a little puzzled by your implied assumption the devices are always stationary`. I was only referring to the test, to show a stationary device too returns errors ranging all way upto 22m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you would almost certainly be better off by pairing some unique device id + coordinates. Because the coordinates you get in the phone can be a calculation based on WLAN and cell towers and not only a GPS signal(for example when the user is indoors) and then you get a higher chance of having the same coordinates. 
Also consider the possibility of malicious users who can fake their location with some utilities, could that be used to compromise your users accounts and/or specific use cases?

Comment: +1 Two users indoor might get the same location. Also the GPS location in Android can easily be spoofed.

Comment: Spoofing I did not think about. It is good enough reason to associate the identity.

Comment: Accepted this answer since it helped understand the spoofing angle. Thanks. @psubsee2003 response also was very accurate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

GPS sensitivity and accuracy are two different things. Sensitivity which also should be accounted here. GPS using hardware tends to malfunction (after long run and varying temprature) and the accuracy can be lost upto 20meters (like you said). In general GPS has its own accuracy of upto 5 meters (in general).

My recent experience with an app that tracks users through GPS made me decide that:

**You definitely need an identity to separate two devices**

As they can return same co-ordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing accuracy and precision.

Centimeter-level accuracy is really only available in professional surveying GPS units, and that is usually after post processing the data.  Even semi-expensive commercial models generally are only accurate within 10-20m, although they can be accurate down to 1m, but that depends on a lot of external factors such as the [GDOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_of_precision_%28GPS%29) and what obstructions are around you.  I have not done any analysis to verify, but a phone GPS would typically fall within the the same level of accuracy.

The `onLocationChanged` method may have 7 decimal places of **precision** but it doesn't make any more accurate, it just means they are providing you with 7 decimal places.  The same semi-expensive commercial handheld GPS models I reference above usually only have 5 decimal places of precision, but it doesn't change the accuracy of the result.

That being said, I have spent a significant amount of time reviewing GPS records done in field surveys over the last few years and what I have found is that while it is improbable that the same GPS is going to return the exact same coordinates multiple times in short succession, it does happen.  Likewise, when you consider you are dealing with multiple devices and an unknown period of time, it is highly likely you will have multiple devices that return the same exact coordinates.

You should always include an identity to identify a specific device and not rely on GPS coordinates alone to identify a specific user or device.

Answer (score 1):

I have many years of experience in GPS app development, what I saw is that it is unlikely that two different devices will ever send the exactly same GPS position (related to 7 digits). But it can happen. I have not made this specific evaluation (but a simular one), but my feeling is that this happens not more than 1 time in some ten thousand cases.
You probably  can live with that minimal chance that this will happen.
Many people would have to buy the app that this ever can happen.;-)
You can also compare two following positions, instead of one. (You can combine these two in one long value)
But the argument that positions also could have been calxulated by cell tower location, is to to be considered. in my app i ignore cell tower locations, i only use GPS.